# Error TF218027 when trying to add new team project

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I get this error:
"TF218027: the following reporting folder could not be created on the server running SQL Reporting Services."

I have no use for sql reporting services in my project, I'm just trying to share a simple project with my partner.

In the group membership section in team explorer it says 
"If your deployment utilizes sql server reporting services you must also configure permissions in that software.."

Apart from the fact that I don't know how to do that, my deployment *doesn't utilize ssrs*

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 2):

Your setup must have some misconfiguration as the New Team Project wizard should skip Reporting setup. Check on the TFS Console.

[image: Incorrect setting]

You can still reach your goal using TFPT command line tool, e.g.

```
tfpt createteamproject /collection:DefaultCollection /teamproject:MyNewProject "/processtemplate:Microsoft Visual Studio Scrum 2013.4" /noportal /noreports
```

The TFPT tool requires the Team Foundation Power Tools.

Also note that to use Git instead of classic TFVC you must use the `/sourcecontrol:None` option and subsequently create the initial Git repo using a tool like my [TfsGitAdmin](https://github.com/giuliov/TfsGitAdmin).