# TF218027 error when creating new team project

Tags: tfs

I am using TFS 2018 update2, I have been given Project collection administrator level access for a project collection. But when I connect using VS2017 and create a Team project, I am getting TF218027 error. Please, let me know what the solution for this is.

Comment: kindly consider adding more details in your question, e.g. your attempt etc

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: i get the below mentioned error TF218027: The following reporting folder could not be created on the server that is 
running SQL Server Reporting Services: /TfsReports/DefaultCollection. The report 
server is located at:
http://<servername>/Reports. The error is: The permissions granted to
user '<domain>/grandmasterflush' are insufficient for performing this operation.. 
Verify that the path is correct and that you have sufficient permissions to create the 
folder on that server and then try again.

Comment: You could try creating it without the "Report" option set, or you need to fix the permission or you need to let another user create the new project.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is very clearly, your account need to gain appropriate permission.

You need to set permissions on **SQL Server Reporting separately** from TFS itself.

TFS, Reporting Services and SharePoint all have independent permissions. The group "Project Collection Administrators" is internal to TFS and thus only gives access to the TFS functions, not the functions it uses on other servers.

The recommended approach is to create groups in AD (eg. "TFS Collection X Admins") in AD; and then use that group to give permissions in each of TFS, SharePoint and Reporting Services.

You could add a 'Content Manager' permissions, detail steps, please take a look at this thread:  [Error TF218027 when creating a Team Project in TFS 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241420/error-tf218027-when-creating-a-team-project-in-tfs-2010)

Another way just as *jessehouwing*  suggested in comment, you **do not have to create with Report**  set, if your team actually no need the report feature, you could also disable the report settings, how to check the report configuration, please take a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32709396/5391065).